# Cropping/Clipping A Sprite

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

How is cropping/clipping accomplished on a Sprite in Flex?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" creationComplete="Init()">
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      public function Init():void {
        var spr:Sprite=new Sprite();
        uic.addChild(spr);
        uic.graphics.lineStyle(2,0);
        uic.graphics.moveTo(22, 22);
        uic.graphics.lineTo(2222, 2222);
      }
    ]]>
 </mx:Script>
 <mx:Panel title="StackOverflow">
    <mx:UIComponent width="200" height="200" id="uic"/>
  </mx:Panel>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Notice that the lineTo completely leaves the UIComponent and Panel.

How can I cause my UIComponent or Sprite, Or Panel for that matter, to be cropped/clipped?  [image]
<sub>(source: [liquidfeline.com](http://www.liquidfeline.com/images/stackoverflow.png))</sub>

I realize I could just change the hard-coded 2222's to something more reasonable, but I need a generalized solution to this, since the actual project doesn't involve hard-coded values that I can alter, but works with dynamic data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mask.

```
var mask:Shape = new Shape();
with(mask.graphics)
{
    beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1); // white, opaque
    drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
    endFill();
}
uic.mask = mask;
```

Comment: I agree, use a mask. But please don't use with ;)

Comment: Okay, this worked.  Anybody else who needs this should also know that you have to add the mask as a child of the component being masked, or it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

You should also try using scrollRect, this will be faster in performance than a mask. Introduction to the [scrollRect](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/11/understanding_d.html) from Grant Skinner.